# Using an other class as a parameter for a class

Tags: c#

I'm creating a bool method called 'AddItem'. I am meant to use a class I create on a separate .cs called 'Item'. I need to use 'Item' as a parameter for 'AddItem' like this:

```
public bool AddItem(Item)
        {
            if (mItems == null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

The problem I am running into is an error saying 'Identifier expected' after the 'Item' parameter. However, when I say:

```
public bool AddItem(bool Item)
            {
                if (mItems == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
```

It makes 'Item' a value and not a reference to my class.

Comment: Do you mean `public bool AddItem(Item item)`?

Comment: I didn't even trying about naming it, I've been coding for about 4 to 5 hours now so I guess my brain is a little fried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give your item a **name**:

```
public bool AddItem(Item myItem)
{
    return myItem == null;
}
```